# FabricJS: set background image to the rectangle

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS 1.5 and I want to add a background image to the rect object. I am able to add using `setPattrenFill` property but image does not contain inside the rect completely. Either I have to use `repeat: 'repeat'` in options which I do not want or some part of rectangle remains empty.

This is what I have tried yet on this:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            name: "canvasBase",
            left: 500,
            top: 500,
            width: localStorage.get('width'),
            height: localStorage.get('height'),
            fill: '#fff',
            angle: 0,
      });
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            fabric.util.loadImage(src, function(img) {
                rect.setPatternFill({
                    source: img,
                    repeat: 'no-repeat'
                });
                canvas.fabric.renderAll();
            });
        }
```

Please Help.